# Fatal error: Cannot make non static method

Tags: wordpress, error-handling, cpanel

Fatal error: Cannot make non static method WC_Widget_Layered_Nav::get_main_search_query_sql() static in class LaStudio_Swatch_Widget in /home2/juliegil/public_html/wp-content/plugins/lastudio/includes/extensions/swatch/class-lastudio-swatch-widget.php on line 397

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQF5H.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrod8.png)

Answer (score 0):

[WC_Widget_Layered_Nav](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Widget-Layered-Nav.html) does not provide any get_main_search_query_sql method. You need to use [WC_Query](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_queryget_main_search_query_sql/)

```
WC_Query::get_main_search_query_sql();
```

Comment: Hey there, Where did you see this in the code as being wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Please visit that link <https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-widgets-class-wc-widget-layered-nav.html#source-view.429>, WC_Widget_Layered_Nav provide a protected method get_main_search_query_sql which is not static.