# Wordpress Fatal Error - Cannot Make non Static Method Static

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Sorry if this may sound like a dumb question. Yesterday I've updated my Wordpress Plugins and suddenly everything crashed, returning a fatal error. I'm trying to reactivate the website via recovery mode, but I can't resume the activity of the core plugin of my theme, because it returns this error

```
An error of type E_COMPILE_ERROR was caused in line 130 of the file /var/www/wptbox/wp-content/plugins/lastudio/includes/extensions/swatch/class-lastudio-swatch-widget.php. Error message: Cannot make non static method WC_Widget_Layered_Nav::get_main_search_query_sql() static in class LaStudio_Swatch_Widget
```

While in safe mode, my website footer disappeared, and so did every product that was showcased in every page of the website. The products are still present in WooCommerce, but the showcase grid were completely deleted.
What can I do?

Thank you so much in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible Duplicate with [Fatal error: Cannot make non static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64111912/fatal-error-cannot-make-non-static-method)

The Code Refference is : https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-widgets-class-wc-widget-layered-nav.html#source-view.429

You could contact the plugin developer to handle this error.

Temporary solutions is :

go to line `130` on file `/var/www/wptbox/wp-content/plugins/lastudio/includes/extensions/swatch/class-lastudio-swatch-widget.php`

change `{class name}::get_main_search_query_sql()` to `\WC_Query::get_main_search_query_sql()`

Comment: I'm trying to do this now. If I understand correctly, I have to change "$_chosen_attributes = WC_Query::get_layered_nav_chosen_attributes();" so that it becomes "$_chosen_attributes = \WC_Query::get_layered_nav_chosen_attributes();"? Thank you so much for your kind reply

Comment: it was depending of the class file, the class inside of namespace, and has been import `WC_Query` class or no.
But on current version 
[referrence](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/f7e38bd1f1c1095c710b7f6a1e5b5e8470f810e1/includes/class-wc-query.php#L425) is not static method. so you must call new WC_Query first